# creating big creature jaws snapping?

Tags: sfx, design

Hey all
Ive tried recording my own mouth doing this, and have pitched the recording down, but it is not really aggressive enough (afraid I might loose a few teeth in the process).
Also layered with different meaty hits etc. 
Im getting there but still need the final thing.

Anyone who has a great suggestion for achieving this? (think, the T-rex snapping sounds in King Kong, which sound just awesome in my opinion).

Thanks alot
Best wishes, Mikkel

Answer (score 2):

Is this just teeth clacking together with little in the middle? Hollow wood, like those percussive frogs you can buy in music stores, might be a starting point, although it might also be too tuned/chromatic/musical. Using actual bone-on-bone impacts that are pitched down might be a useful layer, too. And of course, metallic clacking sounds could be great if you need more weight or high-freq content, if used judiciously in the mix.

Seems like other opportunities for richness, though, could come from a forceful exhalation of breath, tongue/saliva/mouth slaps and other wet sounds, or a grunt/groan that would coincide with a creature's toothy lunge. As you said, meaty hits will do well for filling out the mid-lows. Start hitting those stacks of phonebooks! :-)

Comment: Thanks alot for great suggestions NoiseJockey. Also put in some ive breaking today. Worked well. Thanks again for the new ideas.